# Is it true, that Jackrabbit Oak doesn't support "mix:lifecycle"?

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

As I understand from [source code of Jackrabbit Oak](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/6ca4dd75064e34a87a4a8069d7e4af027155653e/oak-jcr/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/jcr/session/NodeImpl.java#L1284) there is no support out of the box
of "mix:lifecycle" mixin ([only in Jackrabbit](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/ed3124e5fe223dada33ce6ddf53bc666063c3f2f/jackrabbit-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/NodeImpl.java#L3491)).

Is it true or I got something wrong? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I should trust source code, there is no support  of "mix:lifecycle" mixin.